# Packaging for QField: invalid escape sequence

Tags: qfield

I'm trying to Package for QField, but I get the following error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

2023-09-04T19:32:13     WARNING    warning:/Users/Myname/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/libqfieldsync/layer.py:596: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \W
pattern = re.compile("[\W_]+") # NOQA

```
         traceback: File "", line 1, in 
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py", line 275, in showPluginManagerWhenReady
          iface.pluginManagerInterface().showPluginManager(tabIndex)
          File "", line 1, in 
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pyplugin_installer/installer.py", line 342, in installPlugin
          if startPlugin(plugin["id"]):
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 443, in startPlugin
          if not _startPlugin(packageName):
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
          plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "/Users/timhuijsmans/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/__init__.py", line 40, in classFactory
          from qfieldsync.qfield_sync import QFieldSync
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 855, in exec_module
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "/Users/timhuijsmans/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/qfield_sync.py", line 32, in 
          from qfieldsync.core import Preferences
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 855, in exec_module
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "/Users/timhuijsmans/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/core/__init__.py", line 1, in 
          from .cloud_converter import CloudConverter # NOQA
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 855, in exec_module
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "/Users/timhuijsmans/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/core/cloud_converter.py", line 29, in 
          from qfieldsync.libqfieldsync.layer import LayerSource
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 855, in exec_module
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "/Users/timhuijsmans/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qfieldsync/libqfieldsync/__init__.py", line 1, in 
          from .layer import LayerSource, SyncAction
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 851, in exec_module
          File "", line 988, in get_code
          File "", line 918, in source_to_code
          File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
```